# Show actual size of image with \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, resolution, size

**Problem:**

I'm trying to display a photo that is 299 x 153 pixels (300 dpi) in a document but it gets "shrinked" for some reason.

**The actual photo:**

[image]

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[export]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{cellspace,tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\oldincludegraphics[valign=c,#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \includegraphics{phpmyadmin-dropdatabase-op.png}
  \caption{Text.}
  \label{fig:phpma-dropdbop}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**The output:**

[image]

**Desired outcome:**

To get the actual size of the photo to output in the .tex document as indicated by the first photo.

Comment: Does `\includegraphics[width=299px,height=153px]{phpmyadmin-dropdatabase-op.png}` solve this?

Comment: @cauchy42 It seems to fix it in the MWE but not in my template. It gets "wrangled". See updated MWE.

Comment: You redefine `\includegraphics` with the first argument being optional, but call it only with its second argument. As you don't specify the first (which would be the width, I suppose), you have no control. Calling `\includegraphics[width=233px]{phpmyadmin-dropdatabase-op.png}` does what you want. But then, you need not redefine the macro, as the original `\includegraphics` has much more capabilities.

Comment: \newlength{\pixel} \setlength{\pixel}{\dimexpr 1in/300} will give you 300dpi.  [width=299\pixel,height=153\pixel]

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
\includegraphics[scale=1]{phpmyadmin-dropdatabase-op.png}
```

to get the actual size,
if you want to fill in the width of the page, use:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{phpmyadmin-dropdatabase-op.png}
```

if you want to limit the height in some way, use something like:

```
\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{phpmyadmin-dropdatabase-op.png}
```

or

```
\includegraphics[height=10cm]{phpmyadmin-dropdatabase-op.png}
```